# Web.Config file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config

Do configurations specified in web.config in ASP.NET core apply only to IIS Server or it applies to all non IIS servers?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What kind of configuration section are we talking about? Can you please share with us some sample config?

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems the web config is just for the IIS. Standalone hostings with kestrel would not use it.

Answer (score 0):

The web.config will only be used for IIS. It is used to tell IIS to use aspnetcore module and enable some specific setting when host the asp.net core application on IIS.

If you want to host asp.net core application on another server, the asp.net core application will use kestrel.

If you want to modify the kestrel setting, you could use appsetting.json.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1).